# Virtual Host on Apache in AWS Lightsail: what about the mailbox?

Tags: apache, email, amazon-lightsail

I have an istance on Lightsail running a website A.

I want to add one more wordpress site (B), and instead of creating another instance I thought to add a virtual host in httpd-vhosts.conf

But suddenly I had a doubt.

How should I manage the mailbox belonged to the new website (B)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to get answer for this?

Comment: I moved definitely to EC2

Comment: right so you basically had a server from scatch having ubuntu installed and then configured the sites and their dns manually?

Comment: yes, just install LAMP stack (apache, mysql, php), https://vijayasankarn.wordpress.com/2017/01/17/setting-lamp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04-using-aws-ec2/

Comment: add virtualhost on apache and install certbot for certificate https://www.webcreta.com/how-to-letsencrypt-ssl-certificate-install-on-aws-ec2-ubuntu-instance/